# Data Driven Subscription schedule got Failure how to find the error list

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

How to find the failure list in SSRS data driven Subscriptions Schedule below screen shot for your references.

[image]

Regards,
Lingareddy

Comment: What does [Monitor Reporting Services Subscriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/subscriptions/monitor-reporting-services-subscriptions) tell you?

Answer (score 0):

The front end of the Report Server interface doesn't provide any additional information on the subscription errors. You would need to access the logs on the back-end server. The log details can be found in the `ExecutionLog3` View (or whatever number your version includes). You can add the following filters to help find the report:

```
SELECT *
FROM ExecutionLog3
WHERE RequestType = 'Subscription' AND Status <> 'rsSuccess'
```

Since the subscription was partially successful, it may have something to do with 3 of the parameter values causing an issue. Or if some of the values cause a much larger dataset, it could be a timeout as well.